# Replace string between characters in swift

Tags: swift

I have many strings, like this:

'This is a "table". There is an "apple" on the "table".'

I want to replace "table", "apple" and "table" with spaces. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A simple regular expression:

```
let sentence = "This is \"table\". There is an \"apple\" on the \"table\""

let pattern = "\"[^\"]+\"" //everything between " and "
let replacement = "____"
let newSentence = sentence.replacingOccurrences(
    of: pattern,
    with: replacement,
    options: .regularExpression
)

print(newSentence) // This is ____. There is an ____ on the ____
```

If you want to keep the same number of characters, then you can iterate over the matches:

```
let sentence = "This is table. There is \"an\" apple on \"the\" table."    
let regularExpression = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "\"[^\"]+\"", options: [])

let matches = regularExpression.matches(
    in: sentence,
    options: [],
    range: NSMakeRange(0, sentence.characters.count)
)

var newSentence = sentence

for match in matches {
    let replacement = Array(repeating: "_", count: match.range.length - 2).joined()
    newSentence = (newSentence as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: match.range, with: "\"" + replacement + "\"")
}

print(newSentence) // This is table. There is "__" apple on "___" table.
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an extension to do this:

```
extension String {

    mutating func replace(from: String, to: String, by new: String) {
        guard let from = range(of: from)?.lowerBound, let to = range(of: to)?.upperBound else { return }

        let range = from..<to
        self = replacingCharacters(in: range, with: new)
    }

    func replaced(from: String, to: String, by new: String) -> String {
        guard let from = range(of: from)?.lowerBound, let to = range(of: to)?.upperBound else { return self }

        let range = from..<to
        return replacingCharacters(in: range, with: new)
    }

}
```